# Topology: Closed And Open Sets

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Can somebody verify if my solution is correct.

[image]

Comment: What does $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$ refer to in a general topological space?

Comment: For the first part, you cannot use the standard $\varepsilon,\delta$ definition of a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ since your space $X$ is not contained in $\mathbb R$. You should use the definition that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in X for all open sets $U\subseteq\mathbb R$..

Comment: Most people won't bother clicking links to outside sources.  Further, having content in images or on outside links negatively impacts the sites ability to find and suggest related questions and negatively impacts future users with similar questions to yours from finding your post.  [Visit this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to type mathematics here so that your post can be entirely self-contained and so people can find it in the future.

Comment: You pick $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and then consider $f(a)$. This is not correct, because $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$, while $X$ is by definition a general topological space, which need not be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Besides, you should have the $\LaTeX$ source code of your solution, right? Please post it here, so that people can search this question more easily.

Comment: The proof is of a different fact altogether, namely that the metric epsilon-delta definition  of continuity is equivalent to the general topology one on metric spaces. It's not at all about the special function $f$ you defined.

Comment: Please note that math stack exchange supports MathJAX which means that you  pretty much can insert LaTeX code directly. Just surround mathematical formulae with one or two dollar signs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are closed.  Since $f$ is continuous
$A = f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $A^c = f^{-1}(\{1\})$ are closed.
Whence $A$ is clopen.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you know the following:

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, and let $f:X \to Y$ be a function.

Then the following statements are equivalent:

- $f$ is continuous.$\\[4pt]$

  $S$ open in $Y$ implies $f^{-1}(S)$ open in $X$.$\\[4pt]$

  $S$ closed in $Y$ implies $f^{-1}(S)$ closed in $X$.$\\[4pt]$

Using the above criteria for continuity, here's how I would proceed . . .

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A \subseteq X$.

Suppose $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function defined by
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1\;\text{if}\;x\in A\\[4pt]
0\;\text{if}\;x\notin A\\
\end{cases}
$$
Claim: $f$ is continuous if and only if $A$ is clopen in $X$.

Proof . . .

For the forward direction, suppose $f$ is continuous.$\;$Then
\begin{align*}
&\{1\}\;\text{closed in}\;\mathbb{R}\\[2pt]
\implies&f^{-1}(1)\;\text{closed in}\;X\\[2pt]
\implies&A\;\text{closed in}\;X\\[10pt]
&\{0\}\;\text{closed in}\;\mathbb{R}\\[2pt]
\implies&f^{-1}(0)\;\text{closed in}\;X\\[2pt]
\implies&X\!\setminus \!\!A\;\text{closed in}\;X\\[2pt]
\implies&A\;\text{open in}\;X\\
\end{align*}
Hence $A$ is clopen in $X$.

For the reverse direction, suppose $A$ is clopen in $X$.

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Claim:$\;f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Consider $4$ cases . . .

- If$\;0\notin U,\;1 \notin U$,then $f^{-1}(U) = {\large{\varnothing}}\;$which is open in $X$.$\\[2pt]$

  If$\;0\notin U,\;1 \in U$, then $f^{-1}(U) = A\;$which is open in $X$.$\\[2pt]$

  If$\;0\in U,\;1 \notin U$, then $f^{-1}(U) = X\!\setminus \!\!A
  \;$which is open in $X$.$\\[2pt]$

  If$\;0\in U,\;1 \in U$, then $f^{-1}(U) = X\;$which is open in $X$.

Thus,$\;f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, as claimed.

It follows that $f$ is continuous.

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous: $A = f^{-1}[(\frac{1}{2}, 2)]$ is $A$ is open. $A = f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ is $A$ is closed.

If $A$ is clopen, then $f^{-1}[O]$ for any (open) $O$ can only be $\emptyset$, $X$, $A$ or $X\setminus A$ depending on whether $0,1\in O$ or not. In all cases, $f^{-1}[O]$ is open.